# eclipse - Unknown version of Tomcat was specified. windows 10

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I have downloaded the newest version of apache tomcat and I want to connect tomcat with eclipse .
When I try to I get

[image]

I have seen many answers about this but in ubuntu not windows 10 . My eclipse version is 2020-09 (4.17.0) I don't know maybe that's the problem

I also saw that Apache Tomcat version 9 supports JAVA EE , 5,6,7 ,8 Web modules and I have jdk 14.02 as my path . Maybe this is the problem

Comment: What's the version of Tomcat? Is it 9.0.41 which is in the screenshot?

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash yes

Comment: Probably, `2020-09 (4.17)` does not have got support for `Tomcat 9.0.41` yet. Try installing [Eclipse Tomcat Plugin](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-tomcat-plugin#group-details).

Comment: It does have good support. It's just that using a version installed to be run by your O.S. means an unpredictable file and jar layout, and you need to know the layout to gather the right libraries to run it properly with full control of the resulting process for debugging. Like https://wiki.eclipse.org/WTP_Tomcat_FAQ#Why_won.27t_the_New_Server_Runtime_dialog_recognize_my_Linux_installed_version_of_Tomcat.3F mentions, use a zip or tarball straight from tomcat.apache.org instead.

Answer (score 1):

Using a version installed to be run by your O.S. means an unpredictable file and jar layout, and the server tools need to know the layout to gather the right libraries to run Tomcat properly with full control of the created process for debugging. Use a zip file or tarball straight from tomcat.apache.org instead.